# Need to calculate percentage of total count in SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a a table where I have two columns, one is a Date Time column (Test_Complete) and another is alphanumeric Record ID column (RecordID).

I need to prepare a count of recordIDs which were processed on a monthly basis. I have already created a query for that.

```
SELECT (Format([Test_Complete],"mmm"" '""yy")) AS Evaluation_Month, 
Count(tbl_TestStatus.Record_ID) AS CountOfRecord_ID
FROM tbl_TestStatus
WHERE (((tbl_TestStatus.[Test_Complete]) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY (Format([Test_Complete],"mmm"" '""yy")),
(Year([Test_Complete])*12+Month([Test_Complete])-1);
```

This query works well and gives me output like this:

```
Evaluation_Month     CountOfRecord_ID
------------------   -----------------
 Jan'12                   20
 Feb'12                   90
 Mar'12                   40
 Apr'12                   50
```

Now what I need is to calculate the percentage of CountOfRecord_ID value against each Evaluation_Month and append the percentage with the value in Evaluation_Month data.

In the above resultset, the sum of all the CountOfRecord_ID is 200. so the percentage needs to be calculated considering 200 as 100%, such that my result looks like this:

```
Evaluation_Month     CountOfRecord_ID
------------------   -----------------
 Jan'12 (10%)                20
 Feb'12 (45%)                90
 Mar'12 (20%)                40
 Apr'12 (25%)                50
```

How can I modify my SQL query to achieve this?

Comment: So, sql server or ms access?

Comment: Syntax looks to me like Access. Am I right?

Comment: Yes this is MS-Access, I was trying to do some R&D in a small access database before using it in SQL Server because the SQL server table is not prepared yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to add a "subquery field" in your `select` statement with the total count of records. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    (Format([Test_Complete],"mmm"" '""yy")) AS Evaluation_Month, 
    Count(tbl_TestStatus.Record_ID) AS CountOfRecord_ID,
    Count(tbl_TestStatus.Record_ID) / (select count(tbl_testStatus.recordId
     from tbl_testStatus
     where tbl_testStatus.test_complete is not null) as percent
FROM 
    tbl_TestStatus
WHERE 
    (((tbl_TestStatus.[Test_Complete]) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY 
    (Format([Test_Complete],"mmm"" '""yy")),
    (Year([Test_Complete])*12+Month([Test_Complete])-1);
```

Comment: This works! though the division result needs to be multiplied with 100. thanks a lot.

Comment: The important thing is that now you know how to tacle this sort of things. Just remember: A subquery in a field **must** return only one row and one column.