# Calculate Count as Percentage

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, percentage

I have looked around but I just can't seem to understand the logic. I think a good response is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128653/need-to-calculate-percentage-of-total-count-in-sql-query), but like I said, it doesn't make sense, so a more specific explanation would be greatly appreciated.

So I want to show how often customers of each ethnicity are using an credit card. There are different types of credit cards, but if the CardID = 1, they used cash (hence the not equal to 1 statement).

I want to Group By ethnicity and show the count of transactions, but as a percentage.

```
SELECT Ethnicity, COUNT(distinctCard.TransactionID) AS CardUseCount
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TransactionID, CustomerID FROM TransactionT WHERE CardID <> 1) 
AS distinctCard INNER JOIN CustomerT ON distinctCard.CustomerID = CustomerT.CustomerID
GROUP BY Ethnicity
ORDER BY COUNT(distinctCard.TransactionID) ASC
```

So for example, this is what it comes up with:

```
Ethnicity | CardUseCount
0         | 100
1         | 200
2         | 300
3         | 400
```

But I would like this:

```
Ethnicity | CardUsePer
0         | 0.1
1         | 0.2
2         | 0.3
3         | 0.4
```

Comment: Seems you're just counting the number of transactions. In order to find a percentage, you'd need to have the total number of transactions and divide each count by this. So: CardUsePer = (CardUseCount / TotalTransactions)

Comment: Yes, I know this, but I don't know how to program it, since the only way I know to count the total transactions is through SELECT, but it already groups by Ethnicity.

Comment: In the example you linked to, a sub-query is used to return the total number of records. Try something like: COUNT(distinctCard.TransactionID) / (select count(1)
     from TransactionT
     where WHERE CardID <> 1) as CardUsePer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the percentage of card-transaction per ethnicity, you have to divide the cardtransactions per ethnicity by the total transactions of the same ethnicity. You don't need a sub query for that:

```
SELECT Ethnicity, sum(IIF(CardID=1,0,1))/count(1) AS CardUsePercentage
FROM TransactionT     
INNER JOIN CustomerT 
      ON TransactionT.CustomerID = CustomerT.CustomerID
GROUP BY Ethnicity
```

Comment: If this syntax works (and I've no reason to believe it doesn't), then this is the neatest answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your posted sample result to me it looks like you just wanted to divide the count by 1000 like

```
SELECT Ethnicity, 
COUNT(distinctCard.TransactionID) / 1000 AS CardUseCount
FROM <rest part of query>
```

Comment: This only solves the example case, not the general case.

Comment: @BarnabyMercer, Yes true may be but not sure what his exact data is but OP definitely wanted to divide the count by some value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you posted is your answer. As they said in your comments , you just count the transactions, you need to divide it by the number of total transactions. As stated in the answer, you need to divide the count(...) by the total number. This would be done as follows:

```
 SELECT Ethnicity, COUNT(distinctCard.TransactionID)/(SELECT COUNT(TransactionT.TransactionID)
                                                      FROM TransactionT WHERE CardID <> 1)
    AS CardUsePercent
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TransactionID, CustomerID FROM TransactionT WHERE CardID <> 1) 
AS distinctCard INNER JOIN CustomerT ON distinctCard.CustomerID = CustomerT.CustomerID
GROUP BY Ethnicity
ORDER BY COUNT(distinctCard.TransactionID) ASC
```

This will give the result you want.

EDIT: This may be wrong, as i dont know the exact format of your tables, but i was assuming that the TransactionID field is Unique in the table. Else use the DISTINCT keyword, or the PK of your table , depending on your actual implemetation

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Ethnicity, COUNT(distinctCard.TransactionID) / (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TransactionT WHERE CardID <> 1) AS CardUsePer
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TransactionID, CustomerID FROM TransactionT WHERE CardID <> 1) 
AS distinctCard INNER JOIN CustomerT ON distinctCard.CustomerID = CustomerT.CustomerID
GROUP BY Ethnicity
ORDER BY COUNT(distinctCard.TransactionID) ASC
```